# Thymeleaf - url issue : how to name a url using object variable

Tags: spring-boot, url, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, that I am using with Springboot. I am trying to do something very simple: I have a url, and I want to edit the text without editing the url link.

This works (it shows me the website address as a url, I can actually click on it):

```
<a th:text="${c.getWebsite()}" th:href="${c.getWebsite()}"> Website </a>
```

This also works (the button is called "view" but the hyperlink works):

```
<a th:href="@{'/company/' + ${c.getId()}}" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-building"></i>&nbsp;View </a>
```

I want to write on the button not view, but the company's name. And for some reason this does not work:

```
<a th:text="${c.getName()}" th:href="@{|/company/${c.getId()}|}">Name</a>
```

When I inspect the element, I see this :

```
<a href="/company/123456">Test Company</a>
```

So this seems correct, but it does not let me click on it. I have tried lots of different combinations and I have also read the thymeleaf documentation about [url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html), but no luck so far. Could anyone help? Thank you!

Note: this is part of a table… the "company name" (that I want to turn into a url) is in column 3 of the table, then the website is a bit further; and finally the button "view" is in the last column. The button view works, and when I copy the code of that button to the third column without making any change, it stops working (it shows just the button, but no url is working, even though when I inspect the element, the url is there). It is very weird, I got that on both chrome and edge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but found a difference in href-attribute between both working and non-working link tag which could cause the problem:
The working link has got single apostrophs while the other one has pipes...

```
th:href="@{'/company/' + ${c.getId()}}"
th:href="@{|/company/${c.getId()}|}"
```

Does this solve your problem?

Btw: You don't need calling the getters.

```
${c.id}
```

...is the same like...

```
${c.getId()}
```

..., but shorter and better readable.